# How can I verify a handle that is active in advantage dataserver 11 with VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro

How can I verify if my connection to the database is active? I make the connection but I want to know at a certain moment if the connection is active. In SQL server I can do `sqlexec(lnHandle, "select @@version")`, but I need it in Advantage Dataserver 11 with VFP.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to know if my connection is active, I consult in the following way:

```
SELECT Now() FROM System.IOTA

return datetime.
```